# content load dynamically inside quickView/ Popup in larave

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create an application with laravel and I am having some difficulty in understanding how to dynamically load content into a division according to the button clicked from the product icon.

This is the category page

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
@foreach($ProductData as $Product)
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
<div class="product product-7 text-center" title="{{$Product->product_name}}">
<figure class="product-media">
<span class="product-label label-new">New</span>
<a href="product.html">
<img src="{{ asset('images/product/thumbnail/'.$Product->photo) }}" alt="{{$Product->photo}}" class="product-image">
</a>

<div class="product-action-vertical">
<a href="#" class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist btn-expandable"><span>add to wishlist</span></a>
<a href="{{ asset('assets/molla/popup/quickView.html') }}" class="btn-product-icon btn-quickview" title="Quick view"><span>Quick view</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn-product-icon btn-compare" title="Compare"><span>Compare</span></a>
</div><!-- End .product-action-vertical -->

<div class="product-action">
<a href="#" class="btn-product btn-cart"><span>add to cart</span></a>
</div><!-- End .product-action -->
</figure><!-- End .product-media -->

<div class="product-body">
<div class="product-cat">
<a href="#">Women</a>
</div><!-- End .product-cat -->
<h3 class="product-title"><a href="product.html">{{$Product->product_name}}</a></h3><!-- End .product-title -->
<div class="product-price">
$ {{$Product->price}}
</div><!-- End .product-price -->
<div class="ratings-container">
<div class="ratings">
<div class="ratings-val" style="width: 20%;"></div><!-- End .ratings-val -->
</div><!-- End .ratings -->
<span class="ratings-text">(2)</span>
</div><!-- End .rating-container -->

<div class="product-nav product-nav-thumbs">
<a href="#" class="active">
<img src="{{ asset('assets/molla/assets/images/products/product-4-thumb.jpg') }}" alt="product desc">
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="{{ asset('assets/molla/assets/images/products/product-4-2-thumb.jpg') }}" alt="product desc">
</a>

<a href="#">
<img src="{{ asset('assets/molla/assets/images/products/product-4-3-thumb.jpg') }}" alt="product desc">
</a>
</div><!-- End .product-nav -->
</div><!-- End .product-body -->
</div><!-- End .product -->
</div><!-- End .col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 -->
@endforeach
</div>
```

**and mypopup/quickView.html, where I want to load data dynamically is bellow: **

```
<div class="container quickView-container">
    <div class="quickView-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="product-left">
                        <a href="#one" class="carousel-dot active">
                            <img src="assets/molla/assets/images/popup/quickView/1.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#two" class="carousel-dot">
                            <img src="assets/molla/assets/images/popup/quickView/2.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#three" class="carousel-dot">
                            <img src="assets/molla/assets/images/popup/quickView/3.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#four" class="carousel-dot">
                            <img src="assets/molla/assets/images/popup/quickView/4.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: describe more what do your desire for example when click on icon what happen?

Comment: Please click on  quick view button on product image https://portotheme.com/html/molla/index-14.html   it shows popup image. I want it dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can dynamically load the modal/popup

1. Store the product details in data-* attribute of quick view button/anchor tag. Have a skeleton Quick View modal. On click of 'Quick View', trigger a javascript function to populate the skeleton modal with the product data fetched from data attributes.
2. Making AJAX call when user click on 'Quick View' button and populate the skeleton modal with the response data

Going by Approach #1 can you save you multiple network calls to the server as all the product related data (required to be shown in Quick View) is stored as data attributes

**Updated**

Example for Approach #1

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btnQuickView" data-product-name="Product Name" data-product-img="http://shop.com/product/image.jpg" data-product-price="200.00">Quick View</a>
```

**Modal code**

```html
<!-- Quick View Modal -->
<div id="quickViewModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1 id="modal-product-name"></h1>
        <img id="modal-product-image" src="">
        <p id="modal-product-price"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<!-- Load jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('body').on('click','.btnQuickView', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).data();
            $('#quickViewModal #modal-product-name').html(data.productName);
            $('#quickViewModal #modal-product-name').attr('src', data.productImage);
            $('#quickViewModal #modal-product-name').html(data.productPrice);

            $('#quickViewModal').modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can You give an example Approach #1 . my product details is $Product->photo